# Why I cannot find database explorer in my eclipse ide?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am following a tutorial to teach myself about some mysql techniques, but at the step to use eclipse to connect mysql database, this tutorial says that there should be a database explorer nearby the console window, but I did not find it and I've searched a lot, I did not find it at window->show view either.

### My question is how can I get this database explorer in Eclipse.

Thank you, all commentors and visitors, I found data source explorier http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/3,31

And install **oracle Database Tools for Luna**, but it seems that this only supports oracle database, so, let me change my question, **how can I build database GUI connection to mySQL workbench in eclipse?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a view, but try Window > Show View > Other... and search there.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, not find either.

Comment: Sounds like you need a plugin that isn't installed.

Comment: In `Luna` it's called `Data Source Explorer`. It's under `Data Management`.

Comment: @PM77-1, I do not have data management either, actually, I've tried search data in showview, there is nothing, let me search your advise in google and find if I need a plugin

Comment: What perspective are you in?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html   You need `Connector/J` from http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: @PM77-1, thank you, I've tried the tuturial and I can connect to DB using the code, but there is not a GUI for mysql. There is a Data Source Explorer, but I can only use it to connect oracle database.

Comment: You need to create `a MySQL connection profile` using `new Connection` icon.

Comment: @PM77-1, thank you, there is a little problem, the oracle plugin seems not to support the mysql jdbc, but I have fixed it, I will generalize my methods, and thank you again for your patience and time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all commentors and visitors, especially @PM 77-1, I solved the problem with your help,

generally speaking, I need three things to initialize my JDBC tutorial,
1.MySQL
2.Eclipse and a nice plugin as an option
3.JDBC driver, for me it is mysql driver mysql.com/products/connector

use the @PM 77-1 provided tutorial to set up the project to manipulate the database.

But if you need a database GUI in Eclipse like me, you will need a plugin like DBview, my initial one database explorer is no longer in Eclipse. And remember to download the JDBC driver with .jar as the end. It can be find at platform independent version.

Ok that's all.